# Run gradle task in subproject

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-task

I have a multi-project build like so

```
main
|_build.gradle
|_settings.gradle
|_examples
|_|_build.gradle
|_|_simple-project
|_|_|_build.gradle
```

#### settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'main'
include 'examples'
include 'examples:simple-project'
```

Now in the `examples` project `build.gradle`, I have declared a task for all subprojects like so:

```
subprojects {
    task hello(group: 'example') {
        doLast {
            println "${it.project.name}: I am part of example"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `gradle tasks --all`, I get output similar to the following (amoung others):

```
Example tasks
-------------
examples:simple-project:hello
```

Now I try to run that task for `simple-project` like this

```
gradle -p examples/simple-project hello
```

And the output I get is:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Task 'hello' not found in project ':examples:simple-project'. Some candidates are: 'help'.
> - Try: Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 0s

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to run the task in the subproject?

---

#### Edit

If I run this instead

```
gradle -p examples hello
```

then this also runs the subproject task (`hello`)

> > Task :examples:simple-aspect-project:hello
>
> simple-aspect-project: I am an example

I don't want this. I want to be able to run the task for the subproject I want, not all of them at once.

Answer (score 2):

What about a simple `gradle :examples:simple-project:hello`

I think setting `-p examples/simple-project` reduces the scope to the `simple-project` project and cancelled the `hello` task creation which is located in the `examples` project.